# Does the "Magic 2013 Gold Deck Bundle" actually contain any decks?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013

From the sound of it, I would assume the "deck bundle" gives you access to all the decks.

However, according to [this page](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/26466/), the only contents of the deck pack are deck **keys**, and according to [this page](http://steamcommunity.com/app/97330/discussions/0/864957183213240567/), if you buy a deck **key** for a deck that you don't already own, you don't get anything.

So, if I don't already own all the decks, will the deck pack actually give me anything?

Comment: I think you missread the last page. What they say there if you buy a key for a dlc deck, then you first need to buy the dlc deck before you can use the key to unlock the deck.

Comment: @Lyrion: I did not misread it, that's exactly how I understood it.  But "Gold Deck Bundle" implies that it contains all the decks; however the listing of what it includes in Steam shows only the keys, not the decks.  That *could* be because the individual decks are not items in Steam, so they have no way of listing them; or it could be that they're being almost deceitful, and the deck bundle does not actually include any decks.

Comment: But if you look at the image it sais Key bundle... so it might have been an oversight on the steam page or something like that. Or they are deceitfull like you said. :p